# Ошибка AttributeError при работе с QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

Пытаюсь написать функцию, которая вводит данные из QTableWidget в базу данных. Но выходит ошибка.

> name = [ui.table1.item(row, 1).text() for row in range(ui.table1.rowCount())]
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no
>   attribute 'text'

Код для функции копировал из мануала. Там всё работало, а у меня нет.
Полный код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import sqlite3

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = uic.loadUi("test.ui")


def loaddata1():
       connection = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
       query = "SELECT * FROM Бухгалтер"
       result = connection.execute(query)
       ui.table1.setRowCount(1)
       for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
           ui.table1.insertRow(row_number)
           for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
               ui.table1.setItem(row_number, column_number,QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
       connection.close()

def insertdata1():
    name = [ui.table1.item(row, 1).text() for row in range(ui.table1.rowCount())]
    #fam = (ui.table1.item(row, 2).text() for row in range(ui.table1.rowCount()))
    #post = (ui.table1.item(row, 3).text() for row in range(ui.table1.rowCount()))
    print (name)

    # con = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
 #        with con:
 #            cur = con.cursor()
 #            cur.execute('INSERT INTO Бухгалтер(Имя, Фамилия, Почта)' 
 #                        'VAULES ("%s", "%s", "%s")' %(''.join(name),
 #                                                      ''.join(fam),
 #                                                      ''.join(post)))


ui.BtnInfo.clicked.connect(insertdata1())
ui.BtnExit.clicked.connect(sys.exit)

loaddata1()
ui.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Тоже попадался на это. Если Вы никак не изменяли ячейку `[i, j]` таблицы `QTableWidget`, то `QTableWidget.item(i, j)` возвращает `None`. Я понял это так. Довольно странное поведение.

Comment: Ничего странного, если количество столбцов в таблице table1 меньше, чем запрашиваем вот тут (то есть, по-факту, один столбец) `ui.table1.item(row, 1).text()`. Сколько столбцов в таблице?

Comment: @Alexander , четыре столбца.